# How to compile and add the form designed by user to a project

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, compilation, exe

I am going to let users create `Forms` during `RunTime` and add them to a project. I have done the designing and the UI of the form with the help of an open source `Form Designer`.

Here is the image of the `Form Designer`: [image]

Lets assume I have the Form1.cs and Form1.cs[Designer] files which are enough for a `WinForm`. But how do I compile it to a DLL or an EXE and add it to the project? Any ideas? Any clues?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

It creates this code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;


    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 49);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 94);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 184);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 24);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // form1
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }


}
```

I will do some extra coding to the rest of the code myself. but I dont know how to compile it and add it to the main exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is System.CodeDom.Compiler
i think Form1.cs will contain no code (other then InitializeComponents call in constructor). so if you merge it with the designer code with simple string operations your job will be easier.

Comment: I edited my question. I will do the simple string operations as you said. but how should I add the newly created wiwnform to the main exe?

Comment: you cant. only workaround would be copying main.exe to another location and modify it. then use a seperate simple exe, launch it just before shutting down main.exe and let it move it to the desired location. but if i were you, i would save the resulting dynamicaly created assembly to a location such as /DynamicForms and load from it like in your other question.